# Extracting unique values from an array of objects where value is a nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

Let's say I've got the following array of objects in JavaScript:

```js
const requests = [
  {
    id: 1,
    person: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    person: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    person: {
      id: 2
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    person: {
      id: 3
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    person: {
      id: 2
    }
  }
]
```

And what I've written below will go over each item in the array, and then create a new array containing just the `person` object.

```js
const requestsPeopleIds = []
for (const request of requests) {
  requestsPeopleIds.push(request.person.id)
}
```

I then take that new array and create another new array using `Set` to remove the duplicate `id`s:

```js
const uniquePeopleIds = Array.from(new Set(requestsPeopleIds))
```

The final result is as I'd expect:

```js
console.log(uniquePeopleIds) // [1, 2, 3]
```

where these are the unique `id`s of the people who made a request. So out of the `5` requests, these were made by `3` people.

There must be a more efficient way of doing this, so I'm reaching out to you `stack overflow` JS gurus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define _"efficent"_. In regards to CPU cycles, memory usage, ... - Unless we are talking about hundreds of thousands of requests, or some really strict memory restrictions this is another case of micro-optimization which is probably not useful or even necessary.

Comment: This is pretty much as efficient as you can get. It's an `O(n)` solution that goes over the input three times max. You can shave off one iteration if you skip making the final array and just consume the iterator of the Set and there might be some slightly more efficient iteration methods in some circumstances but overall from complexity angle it seems as good as it gets.

Comment: @VLAZ - I disagree.  It's always going to be O(n log n) because you will always have to iterate through each item in the original array and then search through the set of unique values that you are composing.

Comment: @mankowitz there is no search, though. Adding to a Set is `O(1)` operation, iteration over set/array is `O(n)`. This is doing iteration and addition, for a total of `O(n)`.

Comment: I am sorry that I misled you. Please, see my updated answer. It looks like the fastest solution can varies and depends on many factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got the basics. Here's a way to tighten the code:

```
var ids = new Set;
requests.forEach(i => ids.add(i.person.id));
```

Comment: Why not just `var ids = new Set(ids.map(i => i.person.id));`?

Comment: @StepUp - thanks for the performance tests, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with `map` method and spread syntax `...`.

```js
const requests = [{"id":1,"person":{"id":1}},{"id":2,"person":{"id":1}},{"id":3,"person":{"id":2}},{"id":4,"person":{"id":3}},{"id":5,"person":{"id":2}}]
const result = [...new Set(requests.map(({ person: { id }}) => id))]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is this more efficient? Because I suspect it'd be about the same performance-wise.

Comment: And this is in which way more "efficent"? Lines of code because you've replaced the a `for...of...` + `.push()` with a `.map()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making an object by the person's id as a key and get the keys of the object.

```js
const requests = [{"id":1,"person":{"id":1}},{"id":2,"person":{"id":1}},{"id":3,"person":{"id":2}},{"id":4,"person":{"id":3}},{"id":5,"person":{"id":2}}]


// Take an empty object
const uniques = {};

// Iterate through the requests array and make person's id as a
// key of the object and put any value at this index (here I put 1).
requests.forEach(request => (uniques[request.person.id] = 1));

// Finally get the keys of the unique object.
console.log(Object.keys(uniques));
```

Comment: And is this more efficient than a Set?

Comment: The set answer is nice. I don't know the cost of adding new item to a Set. But this approach takes O(n) times. It's good I think.

Comment: OP asked for a *more* efficient method. And the code by OP is already `O(n)`.

Comment: There is no chance of reducing the time complexity under O(n). I think what did he want is code style efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

I've done some research and have inferred some interesting facts:

1. It looks like when we have very various data and larger array, then `Set` collection shows not best results. `Set` is very optimized collection, however, in my view, it should always check whether element is already added into `Set`. And this checking will take `O(n)` complexity. But we can use simple JavaScript `object`. Checking whether `object` contains key is O(1). So `object` will have huge advantage over `Set`.
2. `foreach` arrow function is very convenient, however, simple `for` loop is faster.
3. Adding `console.log` makes `Set` the most fastest solution, however, without `console.log`, the most fastest solution is combination of `for` loop and `object`.

So the most performant code without `console.log()` looks like this:

```
const hashMap = {};
const uniques = [];
for (let index = 0; index < requests.length; index++) {  
  if (!hashMap.hasOwnProperty(requests[index].person.id)){
      hashMap[requests[index].person.id] = 1;
      uniques.push(requests[index].person.id);
  }
}
```

However, the most performant code with `console.log()` looks like this(I cannot understand the reason why it happens. It would be really great to know why it happens):

```
var ids = new Set;
requests.forEach(i => ids.add(i.person.id));
console.log(ids)
```

Tests:

- [with console.log](https://jsbench.me/gmk83bl9f4/2)
- [without console.log](https://jsbench.me/gmk83bl9f4/1)

Comment: Is this more efficient than using a Set?

Comment: @downvoter what's reason tp downvote? It would be really helpful to know. It will help to improve my answer